# Testing Apex Trigger with Asynchronous HTTP Callouts

Tags: unit-test, callout, httprequest, after-trigger, asynchronous

I have an apex trigger f_contactPushNotificationTrigger that should fire when a new contact is created. This trigger call f_PushNotification class used to Post data.

I used @future to make this task asynchronous Since the trigger makes HTTP callouts. Correct no?

The problem I am facing is creating a testing unit for the trigger and f_PushNotification class so I can deploy my code.

I have tried the Mock generation response (but the problem I am facing is that @future does not make it possible to return the response) and Test.StartTest() but both not working.

Below the error I got:

> f_contactTriggerTest  test    Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts Stack Trace: null
>
> f_GetRelatedContactsId    test    Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts Stack Trace: null

So it seems a conflict is happening with another trigger: f_GetRelatedContactsId     that runs after insert on contact but does not have any HTTP callout.

So should I also stop this trigger for testing?

Could you please help me!

Trigger:

```
trigger f_contactPushNotificationTrigger on Contact (after insert) 
{
      for(contact con:trigger.new)
    {
            f_PushNotification.sendNotification(con.FirstName);
    }
}
```

f_PushNotification:

```
public class f_PushNotification {

@future (callout=true)
public static void sendNotification(String text) {

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://---');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8');
    // Set the body as a JSON object
    request.setBody('{"text":"'+text+'"}');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // Parse the JSON response
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) 
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    else 
        System.debug(response.getBody());

}}
```

Tests:

```
@isTest
public class f_contactPushNotificationTest
{ 
    @isTest static void testCallout() 
    {
        Contact con = new Contact (FirstName = 'FnamePushNotification');
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        Test.startTest();
        insert con;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Testing documentation I followed:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Mock Generation:

```
    @isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('https://forestsal.xyz/sendNotification.php', req.getEndpoint());
  

  System.assertEquals('Post', req.getMethod());
    
    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{"FirstName":"test"}');
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
}}
```

Comment: 1) You have to have testmethods on triggers to deploy; 2) the second error looks related to a different testmethod. Solve one problem at a time; 3) use [edit] to show your mock HTTP class; 4) are there multiple triggers on Contact or just the one (again, use [edit])?. Avoid answering in comments

Comment: @cropredy Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question. Could you please help

Comment: It seems to me that you have multiple triggers firing on Contact insert.  Best practice is to have a single trigger per SObject and dispatching to trigger handler class(es)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the importance of applying the  System.assertEquals() method which ensured the code coverage.

Thank you for your support.

> https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_future_methods